# Cell lines of table not aligned cleanly

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I'm trying to make a small table, but where only certain cell lines are drawn. I followed a general code outline I found elsewhere (the "Spanning in both directions simultaneously" part of this document: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables), but when I compile, the ends of the lines defining the cells "overhang" - they don't match cleanly. (Disclaimer: I'm not sure this is the best way to draw this table, but it's what I've come up with.) Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc|c|}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Y$} \\ 
\cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & 2  \\
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$T$}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & $q_{11}$ & $q_{12}$ \\
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2} & $q_{21}$ & $q_{22}$ \\ 
\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It happens whether I compile with TeXnicCenter on a Windows PC or TeXShop on a Mac. The table doesn't look good whether I view the PDF after compiling within the program, or if I open it separately with Adobe.

Comment: Thanks for adding the picture, @David Carlisle. However, your picture appears fine. This is why I'm confused - I wonder if it's my specific program/computer that causes this?

Comment: Additionally, in reality, I have other content in the frame in addition to this table, and when I compile *that* frame, the lines "hang off" horizontally, not vertically (as I personally get when I compile the code I provided above).

Comment: well the pic was made from an unedited version of your code. Try doing as I did and cut and paste your example off the website into a new document and try that. Perhaps you have some invisible control characters messing up your table?

Comment: No, strangely enough, it still has overhanging lines even when I copy and paste it from here, and put it in an entirely new window within TeXnicCenter, that I just opened and saved fresh for this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In comments you say the lines look wore in your example, but I can't debug that (although the most common reason is having code after the last `\\` and before `\end{tabular}` which makes a spurious unfinished last row so the vertical lines hang down.

But the rules in a latex table are always at the *right* edge of the column (except the first column which has two rules) so when using `\multicolumn` you should always add the rule on the right never on the left except the first column, otherwise, in general the vertical rules will not line up.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document} 
\centering

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Y} \\ 
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&& 1 & 2  \\
\cline{2-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{T} &
1& q_{11} & q_{12} \\
\cline{2-4}
&
2 & q_{21} & q_{22} \\ 
\cline{2-4}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Than you so much! You did what I wanted to do, but didn't understand how to do: I wanted to get rid of the two `&` on the first line so I could indeed specify `$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}$` as you did, but didn't think to use `multicolumn` in their place (obvious now). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that table easily with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{ccc}[first-row,first-col,corners=NW,hvlines]
&   & \Block{1-2}{Y}  \\
&   & 1      & 2      \\
\Block{2-1}{T}
& 1 & q_{11} & q_{12} \\
& 2 & q_{21} & q_{22} 
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If you want all the columns with the same width, it's possible with the key `columns-width=auto`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{ccc}%
  [first-row,first-col,corners=NW,hvlines,columns-width=auto]
&   & \Block{1-2}{Y}  \\
&   & 1      & 2      \\
\Block{2-1}{T}
& 1 & q_{11} & q_{12} \\
& 2 & q_{21} & q_{22} 
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]